# Watir-webdriver 64bit windows7 cannot open any browser with error unexpected response, code = 502, content-type = "text/html"

Tags: browser, windows-7, 64-bit, watir-webdriver

Env-
64bit Windows 7
ruby 1.9.2-P290
rubygems 1.8.24
Watir 4.0.2

When try to create a browser (Chrome or IE) instance, it will fail with below errors
When try to create a Firefox instance, it will open the Firefox and then close automatically with the same errors.

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'rubygems'  
=> true  
irb(main):002:0> require 'watir-webdriver'  
=> true  
irb(main):003:0> ie = Watir::Browser.new:chrome  
Started ChromeDriver  
port=9515  
version=23.0.1240.0  
log=C:\Users\y93529\chromedriver.log  
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: unexpected response, code=502, conte
nt-type="text/html"
<HEAD><TITLE>Connection refused</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="white" FGCOLOR="black"><H1>Connection refused</H1><HR>
<FONT FACE="Helvetica,Arial"><B>
Description: Connection refused</B></FONT>
<HR>
<!-- default "Connection refused" response (502) -->
</BODY>
    from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.27.2/lib/sele
nium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:66:in `create_response'
    from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.27.2/lib/sele
nium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:66:in `request'
    from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.27.2/lib/sele
nium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
    from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.27.2/lib/sele
nium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:615:in `raw_execute'
    from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.27.2/lib/sele
 nium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:92:in `create_session'
    from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.27.2/lib/sele
 nium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:68:in `initialize'
    from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.27.2/lib/sele
nium/webdriver/chrome/bridge.rb:29:in `initialize'
    from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.27.2/lib/sele
nium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:37:in `new'
    from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.27.2/lib/sele
nium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:37:in `for'
    from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.27.2/lib/sele
nium/webdriver.rb:67:in `for'
    from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.2/lib/watir-we
bdriver/browser.rb:46:in `initialize'
    from (irb):3:in `new'
    from (irb):3
    from C:/ruby/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

One point to add -
The same environment in 32bit windows 7, everything works good. I doubt if there is some difference of the supporting of webdriver between 64bit win7 and 32bit win7

Any advice will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Even your patch level of 1.9.2 is old. I'm not sure it will fix it, but did you consider updating your ruby?

Comment: Thanks Dave. I tried on the latest ruby 1.9.3-p362. It has the same issue. The same environment works good on 32bit win7, so I'm starting to concern about if it is the 64bit win7's issue.

Comment: I mean, I'm not sure if the ruby and watir-webdriver support 64bit Win7 very well.

Comment: I am able to start Chrome on Win 7 64bit without any issues, so I do not think it is a 64bit specific issue.

Comment: Thanks Justin. You are correct, it is not the 64bit win7 problem, but a proxy problem. I will post the way it was resolved.

Answer (score 2):

It was solved! 
My network has a proxy, when I tried to install the watir, I configured the command line with the proxy, so the command line can download and install watir. After installation, I did NOT delete the proxy that I configured, it was still in the envrionment variables. That's why it fails each time I tried to start a browser with watir-webdriver. Delete this proxy, everything works fine.

Thanks guys for your participate in solving this problem.

Comment: Works for me too. Just removed the http_proxy/https_proxy environment variables from the session. Although I need the proxy for reaching the url, so I used:

browser = Watir::Browser.new(:chrome, switches: %w{--proxy-server=<host>:<port>})